# Converting javascript function call to typescript function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm converting an old an older angular 2 app to angular 5.  Now I'm very new to typescript and not finding much help online.  What I'm curious about is in my code same below I'm using a service to create a dialog.  Within that I'm calling a function via :

```
tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
```

and I'm wondering how to do this.  Also is there a equivalent in typescript for the handling of tempModalDefaults.controller in typescript when the .controller hasn't been defined.  Also how do I handle the angular.extend instances?

Fulle Code :

```
    function show(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
        //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
        var tempModalDefaults = {};
        var tempModalOptions = {};

        //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in service
        angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

        //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in service
        angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

        if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
            tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
                $scope.modalOptions.ok = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close(tempModalOptions.okResult);
                };
                $scope.modalOptions.close = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
                $scope.modalOptions.rename = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close(tempModalOptions.bodyText);
                };
            }
        }

        return $modal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your type at `var tempModalDefaults = {};` or define it as `any`.

i.e.

```
var tempModalDefaults: any = {}
// or
var tempModelDefaults = {} as YourType
// or
var tempModelDefaults: YourType = {} as any 
// `as any` is needed because `{}` will not match `YourType`
```